# replacing variable in a string(url) with a list of values in R

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to generate URLs that follow a standard pattern: abc.xvz/var/

I have a list of values, which I want to insert in the place of 'var'

my code looks something like:

```
library(gsubfn)

t <- function(l){
u <- "abc.xyz/var/"
gsubfn(pattern = 'var',x = u, replacement = l)
}

test <- do.call(t, list)
```

however, I get the unused arguments error, and the result makes use of only the first item inside *list*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lapply`:

```
u <- "abc.xyz/var/"
urls <- lapply(l, function(x) gsub("var", x, u))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sapply` with `t` to get a `vector` output

```
sapply(lst, t)
```

where `lst` is the `list` of urls.

Comment: I'm sorry, but nothing is downvoted here, as far as I can see. Your and Tim's answer both work. I figured I should be using apply family of functions here. Thanks!